# Some questions about scipy.optimize.linprog

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am trying to move from OpenOpt (seems to be outdated) to scipy.optimize. The following questions come to my mind:

1. I have a linear programming problem with one equality constraint, so A_eq in my case has just one row and B_eq is a simple number. However scipy expects A_eq to have exactly two rows? Why? I moved around this by adding a zero row, but what to do with three equality constraints?
2. Why does optimize.linprog not accept bounds of type "optimize.Bounds"? optimize.minimize does ...?

Here is an linear programming example to make it more clear:

```
import numpy
from scipy import optimize

c = [0.056,0.0001,0.2099,0.1429,0.0682]
Aeq = numpy.ones(len(c))
beq = 1 # (sum(ci*xi) = 1)
bounds = [(0, 0.4), (0, 0.4), (0, 0.4), (0, 0.4), (0, 0.4)]
min = optimize.linprog(c, A_eq=Aeq, b_eq=beq, bounds=bounds)
```

This gives me:

```
ValueError: Invalid input for linprog: A_eq must have exactly two dimensions, and the number of columns in A_eq must be equal to the size of c
```

The same problem is running fine with openopt LP. So this is my first question: What is the problem if I just need one equality constraint?

To overcome this issue I did the following:

```
beq = [1, 0]
Aeq = numpy.array([numpy.ones(len(rendite)), numpy.zeros(len(rendite))])
min = optimize.linprog(c, A_eq=Aeq, b_eq=beq, bounds=bounds)
```

Now its running and giving senseful results ... Mathematically still the same ...

Second question is why bounds in the following form is not working for linprog (it is working for minimize):

```
bounds = optimize.Bounds([0,0,0,0,0],[0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4])
```

Gives:

```
TypeError: Invalid input for linprog: unable to interpret bounds, check values and dimensions: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Bounds'
```

Comment: What do you mean by linear programming problem with one equality constraint? You cannot form a simplex by simply one constraint, right? Do you have any non-negative variable constraints in your Liner Programming Problem? I think it would be more clear if you could show us your Linear Programming Problem.

Comment: Your explanation seems clear, but it will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be copied and run.

Comment: I have added an example to make it more clear. Hope this helps.

Comment: You two questions, while both about `linprog`, are not really related.  Perhaps the question about the bounds could be moved to its own question.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have just one equation, `linprog` still requires `A_eq` to be a two-dimensional array.  In your case, you need the array to have one row and five columns, so the shape is `(1, len(c))`.  This works with your original example:

```
Aeq = numpy.ones((1, len(c)))
```

E.g.

```
In [162]: Aeq = numpy.ones((1, len(c)))

In [163]: result = optimize.linprog(c, A_eq=Aeq, b_eq=beq, bounds=bounds)

In [164]: result
Out[164]: 
     con: array([-5.01691066e-09])
     fun: 0.036080001744793845
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 5
   slack: array([], dtype=float64)
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([4.00000002e-01, 3.99999994e-01, 3.33883773e-09, 7.04591333e-09,
       1.99999999e-01])
```

---

If you have at least version 1.6.0 of SciPy, you might consider using the HiGHS solver instead of the original `'interior-point'` method.  Here's what I get when using the HiGHS interior point method:

```
In [175]: result = optimize.linprog(c, A_eq=Aeq, b_eq=beq, bounds=bounds, method='highs-ipm')

In [176]: result
Out[176]: 
           con: array([0.])
 crossover_nit: 0
           fun: 0.03608
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
           nit: 6
         slack: array([], dtype=float64)
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([0.4, 0.4, 0. , 0. , 0.2])
```